# dart angular2 - function in sub-component

Tags: angular, dart, components

I do not manage to call a function within the template of a subcomponent :

For instance, the following doesn't work :

```
<button onclick="{{myFunction()}}">
```

Nothing is displayed, I have the error : Could not find asset MyOuterComponent.dart.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping something with curly braces {{}} is an expression. It is meant for printing a value. What you are trying to do is calling a function. SO just remove the curly braces and assign it with ng-click e.g:

```
<button (click)="myFunction()">Save</button>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your time. It doesn't work. Are you sure it can be done this way in the dart version of angular2 ?

Comment: You are correct it won't work in dart. I will update the answer. My bad

Comment: Here is a reference to the api: 
https://angular.io/docs/dart/latest/guide/user-input.html